# Highlighting Values in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Good Evening all,
I have made a pandas DataFrame from an excel spreadsheet. I am trying to highlight the names in this list that have logged in at 9:01:00 etc. Anyone who has logged in past the hour or half hour by 1 minute, but excluding those that have logged in early eg 07:59:00 or 07:29:00. EG. Those with * around the time. I am a complete amateur coder so I apologise. If things could be put in the simplest form without assuming a great degree of knowledge I would very much appreciate it. Also, if this is incredibly complex/ impossible I also apologise.

```
 Name     Login\nTime
0            ITo    07:59:09
1            Ann    07:59:13
2        Darryll    07:59:24
3         Darren    07:59:31
4          FlorR    07:59:42
5           Colm    07:59:56
6       NatashaBr   07:59:59
7        AlexRobe   07:59:59
8    JonathanSinn   08:00:02
9       BrendanJo   08:00:04
10      DanielCov   08:00:15
11             RW   08:00:17
12      SaraHerrma  08:00:26
13     RobertStew   08:00:37
14      JasonBal    *08:04:36*
17      KevinAll    08:59:52
18           JFo    09:00:05
19     LiviaHarr    09:00:22
20       Patrick    *09:01:36*
24         SianDi   09:30:32
25     AlisonBri    09:59:27
26       MMulholl   10:00:02
27   TiffanyThom    10:00:07
29     GeorgeEdw    11:00:00
30       JackSha    11:00:50
31        UsmanA    11:59:46
32     LewisBrad    12:02:30
34    RyanmacCor    12:59:20
35  GerardMcphil    12:59:56
36        TanjaN    13:00:07
37  MartinRichar    13:30:08
38    MarkBellin    13:30:20
39     KyranSpur    13:30:24
40       RichRam    13:58:53
41    OctavioSan    14:30:10
42      CharlesS    16:45:07
43    DanielHoll    16:50:55
44    ThomasHoll    16:59:45
45       RosieFl    16:59:56
46      CiaranMur   17:00:01
47      LouiseDa    17:29:29
48     WilliamAi    17:30:02
```

Comment: The pandas styling guide should have everything you need: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Comment: What do you mean by highlight ? create a new column so you can filter? can you show ur expected output

Comment: Creating a new column would work. Or just highlight them with a colour.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the Pandas styling options. It has an applymap function which helps you to color code specific columns based on conditions of your choice.

The documention (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) has some examples, you can go through these and decide how you would want to highlight the column values.

Assuming you have a DataFrame called df. You can define your own styling function func() and apply it your DataFrame.

```
df.style.apply(func)
```

You can define your styling function based on the examples in the documentation. Let me know if you have any more questions.